# How to access individual values of form data, passed from an HTML page with jQuery.ajax(), inside a PHP script?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm passing form data to a PHP script for processing via JS(`jQuery.ajax()`).

Problem is - I can't figure out a way to access individual form control values inside PHP( e.g. `$_POST['zipcode']` ).

Instead I can only access the data with `$_POST['form']`, which is an entire form represented as one long string( e.g. `string(89)"color=red&color=blue&zipcode=12345..."` ).

How can I access individual values of form data inside PHP script passed from a HTML form via JS?

*index.php(form)*

```
 <form id="myform">
    <select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

*index.php(JS)*

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url : 'PHPscript.php',
                        data: {form : $('#myform').serialize()}
                    }).done(function(data) {
                         var myJSONresult = data;
                         alert(myJSONresult);
                    });
                });
```

*PHPscript*

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["form"])){
$form = $_POST["form"];

$myzipcode = $_POST['zipcode']; // won't work; will be null or empty

echo json_encode($form);

}
?>
```

**EDIT:** *The zipcode field:*

```
$("#zipcode").focus(function(){
                    if(this.value == "zipcode"){
                        $(this).val("");
                    }
                }).blur(function(){
                    if(this.value == ""){
                        $(this).val("zipcode");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST);` to see how the data is structured. I'm not sure this is the ideal way though: Wouldn't a `data: $('#myform').serialize()` be much easier to deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use serializeArray() on the form data instead of serialize.  That will submit as an array.

```
data: $('#myform').serializeArray()
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: But how do I access the individual form control values inside PHP script?

Comment: If you take out the { } and put it like I have above, they will all be available in $_POST["input_name"], where input name is the name of a html form element so $myzipcode should be fine

Comment: Seems to work, but inside my PHP what should I pass to my `isset()` now? I no longer use `form`, so `isset($_POST['form'])` won't work?

Comment: Interesting. One more thing though, for some reason the script works if I enter only numbers into the `zipcode` textbox. If zipcode contains at least one alpha character nothing will happen. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not really sure because it shouldn't matter.  Are you doing some validation on the zip code or something?

Comment: Figured it out. Inside my PHP script I surrounded whatever `echo` was suppose to return/output with `json_encode()`. Thanks ya'll!

Answer (score 1):

Add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax handler and further modify your code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json', // changed to json
    url : 'PHPscript.php',
    data: {form : $('#myform').serialize()},
    success : function(data){ // added success handler
     var myJSONresult = data;
     alert(myJSONresult.yourFieldName);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nothing happens now when I press the submit button.

Comment: i think the problem is with the form serialization, i may be getting it wrong but the OP seems to get the value of posted form field i.e. `zipcode` equal null

Answer (score 1):

set traditional to true like

```
$.ajax({
traditional:true,
//your rest of the ajax code
});
```

on the php end you are getting the value fine the problem is at the form serialization end