# Ajax submit form not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, form-submit

My submit button does not post the data to the $_POST. 
I have been browsing through the ajax form submission problems in this site, but none of the solutions posted work for my case.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('form').on('submit', function(e){

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url:  $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize()

          });


    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="add_item.php">


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="item_name">Item name </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="textfield" name="item_name" />
</div> 

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
    <input class="form-control quantity" type="textfield"     name="quantity"/> 
</div> 


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="capital">Capital</label>
     <input class="form-control capital" type"textfield" name="capital" /> 
</div> 

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sellingprice">Selling Price</label>
   <input class="form-control sellingPrice" type="textfield" name="selling_price" /> 
</div> 

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: any error in your browser console? are you sure your submit event handler is getting called - add an alert/logging statement in the submit handler to check this

Comment: call getting into that function?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I checked my console, there's no error. I tried adding an alert inside the submit(), it pops out everytime i click the submit button. Thus the submit button is working, but it doesn't post any data to action :(

Comment: @Arun Yep, I commented too fast, that was wrong, I deleted my comment right away.

Comment: @Kevin : what does the request look like? What headers are sent (in the "network" tab of Chrome's developer tools) Before your `$.ajax` call, log what you're sending. Log `$(this).attr('action')`, for instance. What's the result?

Comment: @ArunPJohny in my php, i wrote this line to check for data submitted or not. if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

Comment: check your browser developer tool's network tab to see the request... check the submited data

Comment: @JeremyThille console.log( $(this).attr('action')) = add_item.php which is where i'm expecting the data to be sent.

Comment: it seems like the e.preventDefault() is blocking the button to trigger the post.

Comment: does serialize() automatically store the data into the respective $_POST[] variables? Or am i required to deserialize the data?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents the form from doing anything (posting data, refreshing the page), so you can handle this manually in JS, which is precisely what you're doing. Try `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`? If the PHP file is found and `console.log()` returns the correct data, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @JeremyThille is it that i didn't declare the dataType property inside the $.ajax?

Comment: look at your browser's network tab to see what is the actual request that is sent to the server

Comment: @Kevin we have asked that 3 times already, you didn't answer. You need to check : 1) if the PHP file is found (the path is correct). 2) What is sent to it (headers). 3) Its response data. All of this is in the "network" tab of Chrome developer tools. Echo something in your PHP file, and check this is sent back in its response.

Comment: Remote Address:[::1]:80
Request URL:http://localhost/jasper/add_item.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: POST /jasper/add_item.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 62
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost

Comment: I kind of figured out that the submit button is sending data to the php file. Now, if that's the case, why is it that i'm unable to access the data through $_POST['name']?

Comment: This is my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787670/how-to-access-individual-values-of-form-data-passed-from-an-html-page-with-jque

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$_POST['item_name']` instead ...